# Can the parent and child class be same in python inheritance?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

In python inheritance, we can usually inherit parent properties to the child class. However, I do not get the idea of inheriting within the same class. What does this mean?

```
class MyParentClass():
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyParentClass, self).__init__()
```

Comment: If’s you are referring to super, that is *not* inheriting from the class it refers to.

Comment: Nothing, I do not get why you will want to inheritate from same class. it already has all attributes an methods. Besides in your code there is no inheritance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python super() inheritance and needed arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896265/python-super-inheritance-and-needed-arguments)

Answer (score 4):

Every class in python 2.6 and above inherits from `object` unless explicitly stated otherwise, so `class MyParentClass():` is equivalent to `class MyParentClass(object)`. Under normal circumstances, the `super` call is accessing `object.__init__`.

Under less normal circumstances, `MyParentClass` may be a mixin. This is a class that participates in multiple inheritance in a way that adds functionality to the child without being part of the main inheritance chain. I this case, `super` is referring to some unknown base class in the MRO. The reason that you would want to call the unknown `__init__` method in this case is to continue the chain of `__init__` calls all the way to the base class.

Comment: @Alexander. I don't see that this is an obvious duplicate. Certainly not to the question you linked, although there is some common ground.

Comment: I don't think the answer is useful as worded right now. It *seems* (yes, there's also the problem that the question is not exactly clear) that the OP is confused about `super` referring to the same class, which this answer does not address at all. Rather, it refers to all sorts of trivia of `super` that are not wrong but unlikely to help with the initial confusion.